# Problema con Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Descargue hoy en mi pc android studio y tengo un error de renderizado. No me deja visuailizar ningun componente. Este es el error que tengo:

Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Es un tema que no se encuentra en las versiones más recientes, tienes que agregarlo.

```
 <item name="coordinatorLayoutStyle">@style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout</item>
```

Para realizar esto, revisa el tema que este llamando tu aplicación. por ejemplo :

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Light.NoActionBar">
```

entonces dentro del archivo `res/vaules/styles.xml` tienes que buscar el tema y agregar el item:

```
  <style name="AppTheme.Light.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
      ...
      ...
      ...
  <item name="coordinatorLayoutStyle">@style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout</item>
      ...
  </style>
```